# What is the shortcut to "Add Next Line" in Sublime (Linux)?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, sublime-text

In Windows is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Up</kbd>.

And "Add Previous Line" is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Down</kbd>.

My distribution is Linux Mint Rafaela 17.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html) then the linux equivelant of your keystrokes are <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> but there they are called `Column selection Up` and `Column Selection Down`.